# Generate current and power LEDS off a bike wheel

Tags: power-supply, power, coil

I have a bike that I am planning to attach LEDS to the wheels and make them light up when the bike is moving.  To do this I was planning on trying to use the moving wheels to generate current for the LEDS.  How would I go about generating current off the wheels spinning?  Also, will I have to put a voltage regulator on the device to make sure it doesn't generate too much current?  If so do I need a battery or somewhere for the current to go if it can't be used by the LEDS?

Comment: Voltage regulators do not make sure that sources don't "generate too much current". They regulate the *voltage*, not the *current*.

Comment: attach a dynamo.... https://www.amazon.ca/Generator-bicycle-lightpart-lowrider-cruiser/dp/B00H3RDVKO/ref=sr_1_7?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1491408287&sr=1-7&keywords=dynamo

Comment: @DerStrom8 So does that me if we put a voltage regulator on it then the amps will go up if the volts go down?

Comment: I'd use a few constant current diodes (check Wikipedia) in parallel to limit the current from the dynamo.

Comment: AMps will go up as you go faster. You need some form of regulator. However, you should probably use a current limiter, The LEDS will be dim when you are moving slowly, but that would be preferable to just dropping out.

Comment: If it is for navigation/warning lights I would also add a battery to keep the lights on when you slow down or stop though. Btw, I would NOT use a buck regulator for this either. Dynamos make a lot of drag on the wheel, so you really don't want to try sucking amps out of it when you are not moving very fast.

Comment: Do a google on using neodymium magnets for eddy current generators for bicycles, while you are in the idea stage.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a standard bicycle [dynamo](https://www.amazon.ca/Generator-bicycle-lightpart-lowrider-cruiser/dp/B00H3RDVKO/ref=sr_1_7?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1491408287&sr=1-7&keywords=dynamo) like this one.

[image]

You need some form of regulator. However, you should probably use a current limiter rather than a voltage regulator. The LEDS will be dim when you are moving slowly, but that would be preferable to just dropping out.

If it is for navigation/warning lights I would also add a battery to keep the lights on when you slow down or stop though.

By the way. I would NOT use a buck regulator for this application. Dynamos make a lot of drag on the wheel, so you really don't want to try sucking amps out of it when you are not moving very fast.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5QocL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I used a similar setup for a friend, I also added a charging port for his phone, and it worked out quite well.

Comment: How does this work when the LEDs are attached to the wheels as per the question. It seems to me that transference of power might be the show stopper here.

Comment: @Andyaka I guess it depends on how you read the question. If he indeed wants the LEDs mounted to the wheels themselves he will also need a commutator disk on the hub somewhere..